# Publishing Same Application to both Test and Live Caused Redirection from Test to Live

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have Test and Live Cloud Services hosted in Azure. What I have recently done publish the application for the live service, to test service. Since then when I type the Test Url, instantly changes to live Url. Like: test.mysite.com is redirecting to mysite.com. What would be wrong?